# Orbeon header authentication

Tags: orbeon

I'm currently using Orbeon `2019.2 CE` version
I'm trying to configure header-driven method for access control without using Liferay or default `Login/Logout` form in Orbeon.

I have already set these properties in properties-dev.xml
I'm have 2 roles (`form-builder`, `form-viewer`) sending via `My-Roles-Header`.

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.method" value="header"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.authentication.header.sticky" value="true"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.header.username" value="My-Username-Header"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.header.group" value="My-Group-Header"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.header.roles.split" value="(\s*[,\|]\s*)+"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.header.roles" value="My-Roles-Header"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.forward-submission-headers" value="My-Username-Header My-Group-Header My-Roles-Header"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.http.forward-headers" value="My-Username-Header My-Group-Header My-Roles-Header"/>
```

However, I'm still able to access form builder and form runner without sending `My-Username-Header My-Group-Header My-Roles-Header` headers. It should redirect me to `403` page

Comment: @avernet can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

- Form Runner: the default is that each individual form must have permissions enabled or the form will be public. Make sure that "Enable permission for this form" is selected in Form Builder ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control/deployed-forms)).
- Form Builder: see [Form Builder permissions](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control/editing-forms).

Comment: the doc stated only for `Orbeon Forms PE`. I mentioned that I'm using `2019.2 CE` version.
I also tried `Form Builder permission` and send the `My-Roles-Header` but it did not work.

Comment: I had missed that. Indeed if you are using Orbeon Forms CE, then form-level permissions are not supported. You'd have to protect those forms using other means, at the container level or otherwise. Form Builder permissions should work, but of course only for Form Builder.